# Is it possible to detect a clipboard paste?

Tags: clipboard

I want to be able to copypaste passwords from my password manager to arbitrary programs. I would like to clear the password from the clipboard as soon as I have pasted it into another program. Is it possible to detect in Windows/Linux when the clipboard is being read?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with delayed rendering.  Instead of providing the data, you would give a null handle, then Windows will call you back with a RenderFormat message.  Then you would render the data (provide the actual text to the clipboard), and set a 1000ms sleep timer (or better yet, another thread).  After 1000ms, you clear the clipboard.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Could you provide some more details?